# Specify color for Pie Chart Highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I want to specify colors for certain piece for my pie chart.

I wrote some code like this, but it seems not working. Anyone got clue how to work around with this?

```
{
                name: data[i].status, 
                color: function() {
                    if (data[i].status === "Working") {
                        return '#60a57c';
                    } else if (data[i].status === "Stopped \/ Idle") {
                        return '#e7494d';
                    } else if (data[i].status === "Transport") {
                        return '#fac101';
                    } else if (data[i].status === "Headland Turning") {
                        return '#66cc13';
                    }
                },
                y: data[i].val
            }
```

Basically what I want is if the `status` is `"Working"`, then we specify color as `"#60a57c"`, etc. I don't want HighChart auto-generate colors for me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`color` have to be a string.

So try the following:

```
var colors = {
    'Working': '#60a57c',
    'Stopped \/ Idle': '#e7494d',
    'Transport': '#fac101',
    'Headland Turning': '#66cc13'
};

var serie = {
    name: data[i].status,
    color: colors[data[i].status],
    y: data[i].val
};
```

Hope this help you.

[*Reference*](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/ref/#plotOptions-series--color)

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the color to the function pointer.
Instead, try defining the function in a separate location and simply calling it to get a color value within your data.